# Running a php script in browser is execution or read according to the permissions?

Tags: php, permissions, cpanel

I couldn't understand that what would be the problems i could face if i give `0600` permission to all the php files including html content as well in my cpanel as when a user open the php file through the browser, Does that mean the execution or read ?

Comment: PHP files typically don't need execution privileges. `600` may lock out the webserver, though, as it's typically a different user.

Comment: @ceejayoz As the default permissions were 0644 for files on the server. So, Does that mean anyone can read the script content ?

Comment: Yes. That's why anything important really shouldn't ever be on shared hosting. It's too insecure, for this and other reasons.

Comment: Would the website work fine with `600` ? Or will i be facing some problems because of that as the webserver may be locked out ?

Comment: PHP reads the file and runs the content through it's own interpreter which "executes" the code, but it is not executed in the traditional sense like Perl or CGI that requires execute permissions.  As long as your home directory isn't world readable, other users cannot see the contents.  Group/World executable would allow them to traverse, but not read any files.  The webserver may be configured to run PHP scripts as your user by switching from root to your user which means PHP will work fine.  Is there an actual problem?  Secure your home properly then the the individual files are fine.

Comment: @drew010 thank you mate totally understood now !!

Comment: Welcome.  As ceejayoz said, shared hosting is dangerous.  You will still want to set sensitive files to 600 depending on the permissions of your home.  A home dir with 711 and a wp-config.php file set to 644 would be readable by other users if they knew or could guess the path.  A home dir of 700 (fine in most environments) will prevent reading of anything inside even if the file was 777.

Answer (score 0):

`600` permission is read and write permission for the file owner.

However, that would be the server side of the permissions.  Those, AFIAK, don't have anything to do with browser side permissions.

100 is owner execute; 200 is owner write; 400 is owner read.